# miniDIN - style connector with many pins

Tags: connector

I'm looking for circular connector with size of mini din with so many pins as possible. I'm building embeddable controller for Roomba vacuum cleaner robot, and I want to led as many pins as possible from microcontroller through this connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum pin number you can have on standard mini din connector is 9.

[9 pin mini din connector](http://domino2.kycon.com/Catalog_PDF/KMDGx.pdf)

However, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector#Other_non-standard_connectors) there are mini din connectors with more pins.

**Update**

HR12-14R-20SDL from Hirose connectors have 20 contacts in a mini din size.

[image: HR12-14R-20SDL]

Comment: I'm actually do not care about mini din standard, I just mentioned it because  its size. Any other options, say, with 14 pins?

Comment: @darvin Check the updated answer.

Comment: yeah, thanks! it gonna work for me. The only thing is the price - $5, it's ok for one robot, but it not gonna work with serial manufacturing. :(((

Comment: Just cannot find a male for this on mouser :(